# WPF ListBox & Items with Changing Hashcode

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, listbox

I have a `ListBox` bound to a collection of items that have an ID that is used to generate the result of `GetHashCode()`. When a new item is added, it has ID 0 until it is first saved to our database. This is causing my `ListBox` to complain; I believe the reason is because when an item is first used by a `ListBox` it is stored in an internal `Dictionary` that does not expect the hashcode to change.

I can fix this by removing the unsaved item from the collection (I **must** notify the UI at this stage to remove it from the dictionary), save to the DB, and add it back to the collection. This is messy and I do not always have access to the collection from my `Save(BusinessObject obj)` method. Does anyone have an alternative solution to this problem?

EDIT In respose to Blam's answer:

I am using MVVM so I have modified the code to use bindings. To reproduce the problem click add, select the item, click save, repeat, then try to make a selection. I think this demonstrates that the `ListBox` is still holding onto the old hashcodes in it's internal `Dictionary`, hence the conflicting keys error.

```
<Window x:Class="ListBoxHashCode.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Click="Button_Click_Add" Content="Add"/>
            <Button Click="Button_Click_Save" Content="Save Selected"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <ListBox Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding List}" DisplayMemberPath="ID" SelectedItem="{Binding Selected}"/> 
    </Grid>
</Window>

public partial class MainWindow : Window {

    public ObservableCollection<ListItem> List { get; private set; }        
    public ListItem Selected { get; set; }
    private Int32 saveId;

    public MainWindow() {
        this.DataContext = this;            
        this.List = new ObservableCollection<ListItem>();
        this.saveId = 100;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click_Add(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        this.List.Add(new ListItem(0));
    }

    private void Button_Click_Save(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        if (Selected != null && Selected.ID == 0) {
            Selected.ID = saveId;
            saveId++;
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT 2 After some testing, I have discovered a few things:

- Changing the hash code of an item in a `ListBox` seems to work ok.
- Changing the hash code of *the selected item* in a `ListBox` breaks
  it's functionality.

When a selection made (single or multiple selection mode) the `IList ListBox.SelectedItems` is updated. Items that are added to the selection are added to `SelectedItems` and items that are no longer included in the selection are removed.

If the hash code of an item is changed while it is selected, there is no way to remove it from `SelectedItems`. Even manuallty calling `SelectedItems.Remove(item)`, `SelectedItems.Clear()` and setting `SelectedIndex` to -1 all have no effect, and the item remains in the `IList`. This causes exceptions to be thrown after the next time it is selected as I believe it is once again added to `SelectedItems`.

Comment: What type of collection?  Have you tried other collections?   Why not just save it to the db before you add it to the collection?

Comment: Typically Lists and ObservableCollections, but I think the problem would remain the same for any IEnumerable. The full story is I'm upgrading a large application from .NET 3.5 to 4.0 which has introduced this issue. For this reason I cannot easily make structural changes, and this pattern has been used in many places when adding unpersisted items to ListBoxes.

Comment: Are you firing INotifyPropertyChanged on `Selected`?

Comment: @sixlettervariables not in this simplified example (I don't think it is needed since the binding is only used one way), but in the actual application I am.

Comment: Have you overridden `.Equals` for your item class?

Comment: @Dan Puzey yes I have overidden Equals (the reason for overriding GetHashCode in the 1st place). The code for ListItem is in Blam's answer below.

Comment: You are still adding items new ListItem(0) Zero?   As I explained in my answer that breaks ListView.   Items in ListView mush be unique based on Equals.

Comment: Even with unique hash codes I experience the problem with SelectedItems.

Answer (score 3):

> Does anyone have an alternative solution to this problem?

Hash code of the object must not be changed during the object life-time. You shouldn't use mutable data for hash code calculation.

**Update**.

I didn't expect, that my answer will cause such discussion. Here's some detail explanation, may be it will help OP.

Let's look at some mutable entity type defined in your code, which overrides `GetHashCode` and, of course, `Equals`. The equality is based on `Id` equality:

```
class Mutable : IEquatable<Mutable>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Id.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        var mutable = obj as Mutable;
        if (mutable == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return this.Equals(mutable);
    }

    public bool Equals(Mutable other)
    {
        return Id.Equals(other.Id);
    }
}
```

Somewhere in your code you've created several instances of this type:

```
        // here's some mutable entities with hash-code, calculated using mutable data:
        var key1 = new Mutable { Id = 1 };
        var key2 = new Mutable { Id = 2 };
        var key3 = new Mutable { Id = 3 };
```

And this is some external code, which uses `Dictionary<Mutable, string>` for its internal purposes:

```
        // let's use them as a key for the dictionary:
        var dictionary = new Dictionary<Mutable, string>
        {
            { key1, "John" },
            { key2, "Mary" },
            { key3, "Peter" }
        };

        // everything is ok, all of the keys are located properly:
        Console.WriteLine(dictionary[key1]);
        Console.WriteLine(dictionary[key2]);
        Console.WriteLine(dictionary[key3]);
```

Again, your code. Suppose, you've changed `Id` of `key1`. The hash-code was changed too:

```
        // let's change the hashcode of key1:
        key1.Id = 4;
```

And again, external code. Here it tries to locate some data by `key1`:

```
Console.WriteLine(dictionary[key1]); // ooops! key1 was not found in dictionary
```

Of course, you *can* design mutable types, which overrides `GetHashCode` and `Equals`, and calculate hash-code on mutable data. But you shouldn't do that, really (except the cases, when you definitely know, what are you doing).

You *can't* guarantee, that any external code won't use `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` or `HashSet<T>` internally.

Comment: While your answer would fix the problem, as general guidance it's not true: from the [Microsoft documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx) "The GetHashCode method for an object must consistently return the same hash code as long as there is no modification to the object state [...]" - so a change in state can (and often *should*) change the hash code.  That said, I've long thought that this is a failing in the `ListBox` implementation, which seems to rely on the `HashCode` for selection logic.

Comment: Microsoft states in MSDN (msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx) that the value of GetHashCode must change when the object state changes in a way that may affect the return value of a call to Equals(), and even in its examples it also shows GetHashCode implementations that fully depend on publicly changeable values.

Comment: @DanPuzey: You can follow the documentation. But in this case don't be surprised, when you'll get behavior like OP does. Unfortunately, this is the case, when documentation contradicts existing IRL implementations. Of course, you may say "These implementations are wrong", but will this help you? :)

Comment: @Dennis: any object that implements a non-reference "Equals" *must* have a hashcode that varies based on its mutable data in order to function correctly.  I don't think the documentation is contradicting anything here, but there's a dependency that the `ListBox` has that isn't documented.

Comment: Ok, so you've found out that if you mutate a "property" (in the general sense) which your collections have no way of tracking it breaks...Sounds like you should follow Dennis' advice.

Comment: @Matt: how do you alert downstream users that the hash code changed?

Comment: @sixlettervariables Why would downstream users need to be alerted?  As long as equal objects have the same hash and overide Equals returns the right answer then from my experience you can mutate the Hash.  But still something I avoid.

Comment: @DanPuzey That is not correct.  Two equal objects must return the same hash code. Two object with same hash code are not necessarily equal.  See my answer.  All the matters is the Equals returns the correct answer and is called.

Comment: Not mutating the hash in the first place is clearly the best approach, however as I have commented on my question, I am upgrading a large app from .NET 3.5 to 4.0 (introducing this issue with ListBox) and variable hashcodes have been used extensively. I am looking for a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem with your code is that it did not override `Equals`.

`ListBox` uses `Equals` to find an item so if the are multiple Equals that return true then it matches multiple items and just plain messes up.
Items in the `ListBox` must be unique based on Equals.
If you try and bind a `ListBox` to List Int32 or List string and repeat any of the values then it has the same problem.

When you say complain.  How does it complain?

In this simple example below `ListView` did not break even with a change to the `GetHashCode`.

Did you implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

```
<Window x:Class="ListViewGetHashCode.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Click="Button_Click" Content="Button"/>
            <Button Click="Button_Click2" Content="Add"/>
            <Button Grid.Row="0" Click="Button_Click_Save" Content="Save"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <ListBox Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding BindingList}" DisplayMemberPath="ID" SelectedItem="{Binding Selected}" VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard"/>
        <!--<ListBox Grid.Row="1" x:Name="lbHash" ItemsSource="{Binding}" DisplayMemberPath="ID"/>--> 
    </Grid>
</Window>

using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace ListViewGetHashCode
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        ObservableCollection<ListItem> li = new ObservableCollection<ListItem>();
        private Int32 saveId = 100;
        private Int32 tempId = -1;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            this.DataContext = this;
            for (Int32 i = 1; i < saveId; i++) li.Add(new ListItem(i));

            InitializeComponent();

        }
        public ObservableCollection<ListItem> BindingList { get { return li; } }
        public ListItem Selected { get; set; }
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Int32 counter = 0;
            foreach (ListItem l in li)
            {
                l.ID = -l.ID;
                counter++;
                if (counter > 100) break;
            }
        }
        private void Button_Click2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {          
            //li.Add(new ListItem(0)); // this is where it breaks as items were not unique
            li.Add(new ListItem(tempId));
            tempId--;
        }   
        private void Button_Click_Save(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Selected != null && Selected.ID <= 0)
            {
                Selected.ID = saveId;
                saveId++;
            }
        }
    }
    public class ListItem : Object, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private Int32 id;
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
            }
        }  
        public Int32 ID 
        {
            get 
            { 
                return (id < 0) ? 0 : id;
                //if you want users to see 0 and not the temp id 
                //internally much use id
                //return id;
            }
            set
            {
                if (id == value) return;
                id = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("ID");
            }
        }
        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (obj is ListItem)
            {
                ListItem comp = (ListItem)obj;
                return (comp.id == this.id);
            }
            else return false;
        }
        public bool Equals(ListItem comp)
        {
            return (comp.id == this.id);
        }
        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("GetHashCode " + id.ToString());
            return id;
            //can even return 0 as the hash for negative but it will only slow 
            //things downs
            //if (id > 0) return id;
            //else return 0;
        }
        public ListItem(Int32 ID) { id = ID; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for taking the time to test this. I have modified your code and reproduced my error. Will post shortly.

Comment: See posted fix.  If you will use unique place holders rather than 0 then it seems to work.

Comment: This looks great, using base GetHashCode for ID 0 sounds like the perfect solution. I'll try out your fix when I'm back at work tomorrow.

Comment: You can even trick it with the get return (id < 0) ? 0 : id; and use lower case id internally.  You may need to also overide ==.  If you use base GetHashCode for ID 0 then I think it will break on a hash collision with a ID > 0.

Comment: I have copied this code into a new solution, and the problem is still there. Run -> click add -> select the new item (with ID 0) -> click save (giving it a new id). Repeating this for a second item, you will find that the new ID does not take, and selecting other items in the list will raise the conflicting key exception.

Comment: Just tested with .NET 3.5 and there is no problem (as in my actual application that I am trying to upgrade to 4.0).

Comment: This code runs for me.  I have test with several adds and saves.

Comment: I am quite confident this doesn't work, but I may be missing something. I have done some testing and it issue seems to be with changing the hashcode of the currently selected item. I have updated my question with this information. I think I will just have to find a way to remove items (or deselect them) before I change the hashcode.

Comment: I tested it on two different computer and it works fine for me.   I am on VS2010 and .NET 4.0. Then don't change the HashCode.  I would post  an example but my code does not seem to work the same on you computer.

Comment: I have also tried it on 2 machines (VS2012 .NET 4.0) and again just now in VS2010 with no luck. I am copying exactly from above, not using my example in the question.

Comment: Wow I don't know what to say other than it works for me.   Then just give it a unique hash code and don't change the hashcode.